# Draw a network in Matlab from a specific nodes matrix

Tags: matlab, graph

I have a list of nodes and I want to draw the indirect network between them. For example I have the following:

```
S=['A0JLT2 ','A0JLT2 ','A0MZ66 ', 'A1A4E9 ', 'A1A4H1 ','A1L162 ','A1L4K1 ']

T=['Q3L8U1','Q6IAN0','Q76FK4','Q9H8H2','Q6PJR7','P05787-2',' A0A0C4DH19']
```

As it can be seen matrix Source forms the source nodes and matrix Target forms the Target nodes(for example first element of matrix S as node 1 is connected to the first element of matrix T as node 2... and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `biograph()`.
Such function, given the connection matrix (that is a square matrix of order `n` - where `n` is the number of nodes - with `1` in position `i,j` if *i*-th node is connected to *j*-th node and `0` otherwise) and eventually the node IDs (your `S` and `T`) will return a BioGraph object and then thanks to the `view()` function you can draw the network.

You can easily find also some pretty good examples at the documentation page [here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/biograph.html). My suggestion is to read the doc carefully, `biograph()` is indeed a powerful tool with a high degree of customization: you can obtain stunning network draws.

My suggestion is, first of all to write `S` and `T` as cell arrays and not matrices. Since every cell in a cell array is more flexible and nodes can have shorter/longer names:

```
S={'A0JLT2','A0JLT2','A0MZ66', 'A1A4E9', 'A1A4H1','A1L162','A1L4K1'};
T={'Q3L8U1','Q6IAN0','Q76FK4','Q9H8H2','Q6PJR7','P05787-2','A0A0C4DH19'};
```

Also what you did before is to create a long string due to string concatenation, but that's how Matlab treats "row" chars array.

So you have 13 nodes in total and it is time to convert your edge list (source-destination pairs) into an adjacency matrix (or connection matrix). First of all let's map every node name with a unique ID, you can easily do something like:

```
nodeIDs=unique([S,T]);
for i=1:length(nodeIDs)
    mapTable{i,1}=i;
    mapTable{i,2}=nodeIDs{i};
end
```

and `mapTable` will have the form:

```
mapTable = 

    [ 1]    'A0A0C4DH19'
    [ 2]    'A0JLT2'    
    [ 3]    'A0MZ66'    
    [ 4]    'A1A4E9'    
    [ 5]    'A1A4H1'    
    [ 6]    'A1L162'    
    [ 7]    'A1L4K1'    
    [ 8]    'P05787-2'  
    [ 9]    'Q3L8U1'    
    [10]    'Q6IAN0'    
    [11]    'Q6PJR7'    
    [12]    'Q76FK4'    
    [13]    'Q9H8H2'
```

Now you create the adjacency matrix as explained above:

```
AdjMatrix=zeros(length(nodeIDs));                          % start matrix as all zeros
for i=1:length(S)                                          % since length(S)=length(T) you can use either the former or the latter 
    idxS=find(cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x,S{i}),mapTable(:,2))); % find the index in mapTable for the i-th element in S
    idxT=find(cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x,T{i}),mapTable(:,2))); % same as above but with i-th element from T
    AdjMatrix(idxS,idxT)=1;                                % set that element as 1
end
```

Create BioGraph object and show:

```
bobj=biograph(AdjMatrix,nodeIDs);
view(bobj);
```

[image]

Comment: could u plz clarify this a little bit